How to influence the ordering of FacesContextFactory
I have multiple JARs in my lib directory containing the /META-INF/faces-context.xml, of which two contain a definition of a faces-context-factory. I'm getting a ClassCastException when rendering partial requests, depending on the ordering in which the Factories are wrapped.
Is there a way to define the order in which the FacesContextFactory are wrapped?
